# Circuit analysis of series diode clipper circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, transient

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAddN8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm really unsure how to start with this. The instructions said to find Vin such that Vout will be 0.5Vin. The only given is Vd = 0.7 and Rd = 5 ohms. I tried to do a KVL equation but then I don't know what the current is since Vin is not given.

Additional info:
Diode model that is used is the constant voltage drop model with resistance of Rd=5 ohms and forward voltage of 0.7

Comment: Compared to your previous question, you've now clearly left the concept of the "ideal diode", and are now working with a diode that has a more complex mathematical model. But you forget to specify your diode's model – is it maybe the Shockley equation? No matter the model, you've also forgotten to specify the parameters of your diode (something like forward voltage in saturation, or saturation current).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I should have mentioned that Vd = 0.7 meant that its the forward voltage of the diode. Hence, ill be using the constant voltage drop model here.

Comment: Oh, Ok, that makes it... super easy? Then Vout = 0.7 V by definition, then 2Vout = Vin = 1.4 V by the problem statement?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking as well. But then what im doubting about is the existence of the resistor Rd. Would it not affect Vout?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah i made a mistake. Instead of constant voltage drop model, there is Rd as well.

Comment: that doesn't matter. Your problem statement says Vin = 2 Vout, and Vout=Vd is given. so, solved. (Unless your diode model is more complex, AND Vd is misleadingly named; but again, you're still not stating that model! We can't know what's in your head. Please define what a diode looks like for you, and what Rd is in case of your diode model.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit model to be used for the diode is missing in the original question, however the diode parameters provided (\$V_d\$ and \$R_d\$) point towards using a [piece-wise linear model for the diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling). Therefore, your circuit should be redrawn as follows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMpDml.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming \$V_{out} > V_d\$, the ideal diode has a forward bias and acts as a short-circuit. Voltage equations:
$$
\frac{V_{out}-V_i}{R_1}+\frac{V_{out}-V_d}{R_d}=0
$$
With the additional constraint \$V_{out} = 0.5V_i\$:
$$
\frac{-0.5V_i}{R_1}+\frac{0.5V_i-V_d}{R_d}=0
$$
$$
0.5\left(\frac{1}{R_d}-\frac{1}{R_1}\right)V_i=\frac{V_d}{R_d}
$$
$$
V_i=2\frac{V_d}{R_d\left(\frac{1}{R_d}-\frac{1}{R_1}\right)}
$$
Checking numerically if the forward bias assumption holds true:
$$
V_i=\frac{1.4}{5(0.2-0.1)}=\frac{1.4}{0.5}=2.8
$$
$$
V_{out}=0.5V_i=1.4 > V_d
$$